# Angular 2 animation add overflow property on end

Tags: css, angular, animation

I am trying to achieve a slide in out animation and i have the following code

```
animations: [
        trigger('assignState', [
            state('maximize', style({
                height: '*',
            })),
            state('minimize',   style({
                height: '0'
            })),
            transition('maximize => minimize', animate('300ms ease-in')),
            transition('minimize => maximize', animate('300ms ease-out'))
        ])
    ]
```

In order for this to work i need to add `overflow: hidden` to the element but i don't want to have overflow: hidden when is maximized because is messing with my content. I have some absolute elements inside it that don't show because of the overflow hidden.

Is there a way to apply overflow hidden when the minimize state animation start and remove it when the maximize animation ends?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can control this entirely in the animation definition by:

1) Defining the desired overflow settings in your states:

```
state(
  'maximize', 
  style({
    height: '*',
    overflow: 'visible' // or e.g. 'inherit'
})),
state('minimize',
  style({
    height: '0',
    overflow: 'hidden'
}))
```

Then use `group` to define different timing functions for height and overflow. Because then you can use the `steps()` timing function for the overflow property, to make it work like a timed toggle:

```
transition(
  'maximize => minimize',
  group([
    animate('300ms ease-in', style({ height: 0 })),
    animate('300ms steps(1,start)', style({ overflow: 'hidden' }))
  ])
),
transition(
  'minimize=> maximize',
  group([
    animate('300ms ease-out', style({ height: '*' })),
    animate('300ms steps(1,end)', style({ overflow: 'visible' }))
  ]) 
)
```

Note that setting `end` and `start` on the steps timing function defines when the target style is set for the single step. For e.g. the `'maximize=> minimize'` transition you want to set the overflow to hidden as soon as the animation starts.

As an alternative syntax you can use the angular animation keyframes syntax to define the steps as well. E.g. the `'maximize => minimize'` transition can be written like this:

```
transition(
  'maximize => minimize',
  group([
    animate('300ms ease-in', style({ height: 0 })),
    animate(
      '300ms', 
      keyframes([
        style({overflow: hidden}),
        style({overflow: hidden})
      ])  
    )
  ])
)
```

As noted in an earlier comment, the styles defined in the keyframe function disappears when the animation ends, but since overflow is set in the states, they are as we want them to be after the animations ends.

Comment: Thank you the steps thing solved my similar issue. My scrollbar now appears at the very end.

Answer (score 2):

you can use **start** and **end** callback attached to **angular2-animation**

This example/below code is just for the reference purpose.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
        (@flyInOut.start)="animationStarted($event)"
        (@flyInOut.done)="animationDone($event)"
        [@flyInOut]="'in'">
      {{hero.name}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#animation-callbacks

**EDIT**: you can also use **`keyframe`** for your use case.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#multi-step-animations-with-keyframes

Comment: I was thinking maybe i can do something in the animation definition and not use these events.

Comment: I think keyframe will help you.

Comment: As far as i understood styles from transition will not be kept at the end of the animation. So using key frames it will work only during the animation. The overflow: hidden will be removed and the element will show again since height: 0 doesn't work unless overflow is hidden.