# Angular wait for template to update before proceeding with calculations?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to animate from an auto height to zero and back again. In jQuery, I would sniff the height of the auto container, hardcode that height, then change the height to zero and allow css transitions to do their thing. To go back, I would unset the 0 height, grab the og height, reset the 0 height, animate to the og height, and finally unset the styling again to put everything back to normal.

With angular, it seems to not want to do that, presumably because it won't update the template until this function call has completed, despite multiple change detections?

The code:

```
  onMaximize(e) {
    const height = this.headerNav.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    this.headerHeight = 'flex: 0 0 ' + height + 'px';
    this.change.detectChanges();
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.headerHeight = 'flex: 0 0 0';
      this.change.detectChanges();
    },0)
  }
  onRestore(e){
    this.headerHeight = 'flex: 0 0 auto; transition: all 0s !important';
    this.change.detectChanges();

    const height = this.headerNav.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    this.headerHeight = 'flex: 0 0 0';
    this.change.detectChanges();

    this.headerHeight = 'flex: 0 0 ' + height + 'px';
    this.change.detectChanges();

    this.headerHeight = '';
    this.change.detectChanges()
  }
```

I got the maximize to work with the setTimeout, but deeply nesting them or running them in parallel for the restore is not working.

Is there a way to say "wait for the template to update because I have more stuff to do"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest angular animation for that. Please use those and you can have more feasible animation there. Without changing CSS dynamically. Angular change detection and other ng-zone related change firing may not with correct time for those kind of dynamically changing CSSs.

you can follow this official guide if u are new to animations

- https://angular.io/guide/transition-and-triggers

try out this example as well there are plenty of stackblitz as well you can try out those.

other than that in this stackoverflow - [Angular 2 animation add overflow property on end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879451/angular-2-animation-add-overflow-property-on-end) question u can find out simillar maximize minimize animations

```
   state(
      'maximize', 
      style({
        height: '*',
        overflow: 'visible' // or e.g. 'inherit'
    })),
    state('minimize',
      style({
        height: '0',
        overflow: 'hidden'
    }))

------------------------------------------------------------------
transition(
  'maximize => minimize',
  group([
    animate('300ms ease-in', style({ height: 0 })),
    animate('300ms steps(1,start)', style({ overflow: 'hidden' }))
  ])
),
transition(
  'minimize=> maximize',
  group([
    animate('300ms ease-out', style({ height: '*' })),
    animate('300ms steps(1,end)', style({ overflow: 'visible' }))
  ]) 
)
```

follow that